# Routes, Views, Controllers, and Models behaving oddly, caching

Tags: routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I've started learning Laravel (5.1) and have been using the laracasts to get started.

After having the basics working I decided to try my own. I created a project and was doing alright, but then hit a snag. So I decided to create a new demo project to test if I had broken some config.

I created a migration to make a table for pages, with the `title`, `slug`, and `html` columns.

I also have a plane (generated with `php artisan make:model`) model for the pages called `Page`.

I have my `PageController` which uses `App\Page`, and has `index` and `show` methods like so:

```
public function index()
{
    return 'Pages Index';
}

public function show(Page $page)
{
    return $page;
}
```

Then I have my `routes.php` file configured like this:

```
$router->bind('page', function($slug)
{
    return App\Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});

$router->get('pages/', 'PagesController@index');
$router->get('pages/{page}', 'PagesController@show');
```

My expected output is that `www.example.com/pages` outputs "Pages Index", and that `wwww.example.com/pages/about` outputs the about page from the database.

This worked. I then switched back to my main project to test, and I could not get the project to work. I then shift back to my demo project. I tested switching my `$router->get`s to a `$router->resource`, it didn't work, so I ctrl-z'ed my way back to the way the files started, but the project no longer works. I simply get an empty (new) Page object.

I have tried using `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan view:clear`, `php artisan route:cache` to no avail. I've also tried clearing my browser's cache, but nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there something getting stuck in Laravel?

**Update**

As per request, here is my real project code:

`routes.php`:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$router->bind('page', function($slug)
{
    return App\Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});

$router->resource('page', 'PageController');
```

`PageController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Page;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $page = Page::where('slug', 'index')->first();
        return view('page.index', compact('page'));
    }

    public function show(Page $page)
    {
        return $page;
    }
}
```

My index view shows the right Page from the database, however the show only shows `[]` on the screen.

Comment: When you say `I then switched back to my main project to test, and I could not get the project to work`, what the error is? What do you mean?

Comment: @manix there is no error per se, I just get the empty object in my view.

Comment: Delete the compiled classes manually: remove `/bootstrap/cache/services.json` then do `php artisan optimize`

Comment: I'm still getting the blank object.

Comment: Add the routes for your main project! The order of routes matters, so it could be something to do with where you added the code when you copy pasted it.

Comment: @Jeemusu updated my question.

Comment: Probably because your injecting the model into the show method, and then returning it again without making any queries... Your also using facades in the index() method, but dependency injection in the show method, you should probably pick one pattern.

Comment: @Jeemusu I've been trying to just get it to work, I will unify my style once I figure out how to get it working. I am trying to inject the model into the show method, but it should be passed as a complete object with properties (which it was originally) but now I just get [], instead of the object chosen by the `$router->bind`

Comment: I think I figured out a problem. There seems to be a bug in Laravel 5.1.16 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem came from using `php artisan route:cache`, as routes with closures cannot be compiled. running `php artisan route:clear` fixes the problem.